Question- Data Course, learning about sql and r
You’re a junior data analyst working for a local news station and your team uses BigQuery to analyze weather trends. The station’s meteorologist has tasked you with understanding the relationship between wind speed and visibility in 2023. However, you’re working with the newest data and it hasn’t been cleaned yet. Missing values were incorrectly entered as zeroes, and you need to change them to null values before you look for trends. The code you’re using to do this is returning an error message. But don’t worry!
Could not figure it out.
